# Find returns nothing after an insert

Tags: mongodb, collections, meteor

I am trying to understand how to use mongo and get specific result sets. I feel a bit silly as I can find so little on the internet on how exactly this works, it must be super obvious to the majority.

If it is googlable, please assist in helping me find the proper keywords, because I am not getting where I need to be via that route :)

```
 Meteor.startup(function() {
    Users.remove({}); //reset test

    if (Users.find().count() === 0) {
        Users.insert([
            {username : 'Daan'   , password : "test2"},
            {username : 'Miranda', password : "test1"}
        ]);
        console.log(Users.find({}).fetch());
        console.log(Users.find({username : 'Daan'}).fetch());
    }
});
```

The find with {username : 'Daan'} finds nothing.
The find with ({}) returns both records in an array

Comment: there is a massive manual at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/ nevertheless i would not learn via meteor. start off with the mongo shell. and that would be db.collectionname.find({username: 'Daan'})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Collection.insert](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert) only accepts a single document. Try this instead:

```
Users.insert({username: 'Daan', password: "test2"});
Users.insert({username: 'Miranda', password: "test1"});
```

Note you may want to use [accounts-password](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_passwords) instead of generating your own `Users` collection.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Makes me feel well green, but thanks for taking the time to help me onwards with this! :)